# Button overlapping when add uibutton in uinavigationbar in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have a problem when i change viewcontroller, uibutton added in uinavigationbar has been overlapped. I tried below code:

```
    int submit_x = 170 ;
    int refresh_x =100;

    UIButton *refreshbtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIImage *imageRefresh = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Refresh.png"];
    [refreshbtn setImage:imageRefresh forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [refreshbtn setFrame:CGRectMake(refresh_x, 7, imageRefresh.size.width, imageRefresh.size.height)];
    [refreshbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    refreshbtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:refreshbtn];
```

I added above code in ViewDidAppear(). How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to add UIBarButtonItem not UIButton to your navigation controller

```
    UIBarButtonItem *refreshButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshClicked:)];
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = refreshButton;
```

Try that and let me know is it what you after.

//EXTENDED

```
    UIButton *refreshbtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIImage *imageRefresh = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Refresh.png"];
    [refreshbtn setImage:imageRefresh forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [refreshbtn setFrame:CGRectMake(refresh_x, 7, imageRefresh.size.width, imageRefresh.size.height)];
    [refreshbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    refreshbtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIBarButtonItem *yourButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: refreshbtn];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = yourButton;
```

You should add UIButton directly to navigationcontroller.

//EXTENDED

Create another UIBarButtonItem (the same way as above) and add it like that:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[yourButton, yourAnotherButton];
```

It should work fine with iOS6 and 7

Comment: Thanks but i want to add uibutton not uibarbuttonitem.

Comment: See my edited post this is how you should do this. You shouldn't add UIButton directly to UINavigationController, better way is add it as a UIBarButtonItem with custom view. Let me know is it works for you.

Comment: rightBarButtonItem and leftBarButtonItem, i added other button. I want to refresh button near rightBarButtonItem, so that I used addSubview instead of rightBarButtonItem.